# Java: write an array into a text file

Tags: java, arrays, file, matrix

I'm trying to write a matrix into a text file. 
In order to do that I'd like to know how to write an array into a line in the text file.

I'll give an example:

int [] array = {1 2 3 4};

I want to have this array in text file in the format:

```
1 2 3 4
```

and not in the format:

```
1
2
3
4
```

Can you help me with that?

Thanks a lot

Comment: show us what you got !!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a naive approach

```
//pseudocode
String line;
StringBuilder toFile = new StringBuilder();
int i=0;
for (;array.length>0 && i<array.length-2;i++){
   toFile.append("%d ",array[i]);
}

toFile.append("%d",array[i]);

fileOut.write(toFile.toString());
```

Comment: Now you have a trailing space.

Comment: Yes. Im shielding from that with my "pseudocode" comment. But ok, i'll add that in.

Comment: Now it fails with an exception if the array is empty. That might be suitable for the submitter, or it might not. I don't know.

Answer (score 3):

Then don't write a new line after each item, but a space. I.e. don't use `writeln()` or `println()`, but just `write()` or `print()`.

Maybe code snippets are more valuable, so here is a basic example:

```
for (int i : array) {
    out.print(i + " ");
}
```

**Edit:** if you don't want trailing spaces for some reasons, here's another approach:

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.length;) {
    out.print(array[i]);
    if (++i < array.length) {
        out.print(" ");
    }
}
```

Comment: This leaves a trailing space at the end of the line. That might be suitable for the submitter, or it might not. I don't know.

Comment: I also don't know, but that's just a trivial change. I've added it.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I know Tom already provided an accepted answer - but this is another way of doing it (I think it looks better, but that's maybe just me):

```
int[] content     = new int[4] {1, 2, 3, 4};
StringBuilder toFile = new StringBuilder();

for(int chunk : content) {
    toFile.append(chunk).append(" ");
}

fileOut.write(toFile.toString().trim());
```

Answer (score 0):

"Pseudocode"

```
for( int i = 0 ; i < array.lenght ; i++ )
    {
       if( i + 1 != array.lenght )
       {
          // Not last element
          out.write( i + " " );
       }
       else
       {
          // Last element
          out.write( i );
       }
    }
```